# Printing from within properties

Tags: python, properties, serial-port, robotics

I'm trying to make a robotics kit. Its designed to be simple so I'm using properties so when the users change a parameter the property method sends the serial command which controls motors/ servos/whatever.

This is the code at the moment, directly from a previous question I asked on here.

```
class Servo(object):
def __init__(self, which_servo, angle = 0):
    self._angle = angle;
    self._servo_no = which_servo

def get_angle(self):
    return self._angle
def set_angle(self, value):
    self._angle = value
    print "replace this print statement with the code to set servo, notice that this method knows the servo number AND the desired value"

def del_angle(self):
    del self._angle
angle = property(get_angle, set_angle, del_angle, "I'm the 'angle' property.
```

this is then initialized as such:

```
class robot(object):
def __init___(self):
    self.servos = [Servo(0), Servo(1), Servo(2), Servo(3)]
```

Now, this works in the respect that it does change the variable through the getter and setter functions, however the prints in the getter and setter never is printed, thus if I replace it with a serial command I assume it won't do anything either, can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Update: Thanks for the help using the servo file this is whats happened, there are three scenarios the first works and by extension I would have assumed the next two preferable scenarios would work but they don't any ideas?

## This works

```
import servo

class Robot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.servos = [servo.Servo(0, 0), servo.Servo(1,0), servo.Servo(2,0)]

R = Robot()

R.servos[1].angle = 25
```

## This does not:

```
import servo

class Robot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.servos = [servo.Servo(0, 0), servo.Servo(1,0), servo.Servo(2,0)]

R = Robot()

left_servo = R.servos[1].angle

left_servo = 25
```

## Neither does this

```
import servo

class Robot(object):
    def __init__(self):
    self.servos = [servo.Servo(0, 0).angle, servo.Servo(1,0).angle,               servo.Servo(2,0).angle]

R = Robot()

R.servo[1] = 25
```

Comment: Does python have private classes?  ie: A class (type) defined within another class that no outside class can know exists?  I'm guessing you mean a class with private variables here?  Note: Did you check to see if your program can output any print statement successfully?  (perhaps stdout got redirected?)

Answer (score 0):

Using the preferred decorator syntax for properties, this works fine.  It'll also help you avoid issues like this in the future

```
class Servo(object):
    def __init__(self, which_servo, angle = 0):
        self._angle = angle;
        self._servo_no = which_servo

    @property
    def angle(self):
        return self._angle

    @angle.setter
    def angle(self, value):
        self._angle = value
        print "replace this print statement with the code to set servo"

    @angle.deleter
    def angle(self):
        del self._angle
```

Seeing as your indentation is off here, I believe this is likely an issue of indentation in your source.  This should work as well if you really want to use the old `property` function:

```
class Servo(object):
    def __init__(self, which_servo, angle = 0):
        self._angle = angle;
        self._servo_no = which_servo

    def get_angle(self):
        return self._angle

    def set_angle(self, value):
        self._angle = value
        print "replace this print statement with the code to set servo"

    def del_angle(self):
        del self._angle

    angle = property(get_angle, set_angle, del_angle,"I'm the 'angle' property.")
```

Both of these work successfully for me (inside a file called servo.py)

```
>>> import servo
>>> s = servo.Servo(1, 2)
>>> s.angle
2
>>> s.angle = 3
replace this print statement with the code to set servo
```

**EDIT**

To address your new issues.  When you assign `R.servos[1].angle` to `left_servo`, its not creating a reference to the servos angle, it's just setting `left_servo` to whatever the angle is.  When you reassign 25 to it, you're not assigning to the `angle` you're assigning to the `left_servo`.

On the second one, I'm assuming you meant `R.servos` and not `R.servo` which should be raising an `AttributeError`.  But the real problem as I see it, is you should be saying `R.servos[1].angle = 25` and you're omitting the `.angle`.

To (attempt to) put it simply:  When you use the `=` operator, you are changing **where** a name refers to, not **what** it refers to.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x = 2
```

the second assignment does not overwrite the `1` in memory with a `2`, it just changes where `x` refers to.  So if I did something like

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = x
>>> y = 2
>>> print x
1
```

the output is `1` because your are telling `y` to refer to the same place that `x` refers.  Changing `y` to `2` changes where `y` refers to, it does not change the `1` already in memory.

Comment: A no, the indentation is find it just didn't copy to stack overflow very well!

Comment: @user2137452, have you tried using either of these exactly as written?  they are both working for me as expected (see edit).

Comment: also in addition I'm now getting an error saying robot() has no attribute servos when running this code

`code` class robot(object):
    def __init___(self):
        self.servos = [Servo(0), Servo(1), Servo(2), Servo(3)]
        self.cheese = 1


r = robot()

print r.servos

Comment: @user2137452 again, please try using my first code block exactly as written and tell if it works or not, because it does.

Comment: @user2137452 you're gonna need to post more of your code, something strange may be going on.

Comment: Ryan you've been brilliant I've got the code you gave me working but Ive edited above to clarify so extended difficulties, thanks

Comment: @user2137452 ok I'll elaborate on your problems given a little time (really it's own question) but the short answer is you can't do this.  You need to understand mutability and how typing works in order to get why.

Comment: @user2137452 if you happen to c or c++ I can explain whats going on in terms of that.